# How to map two simple js object into a new object?

Tags: javascript

I had two objects and by using them I have to create a third object in such a way that it will map one object1 value with object two key like

```
Object1 = {"a":"1","b":"2"}
```

And object2 be like

```
Object2 = {"1":"alpha","2":"beta"}
```

And it will return me the final object like

```
Object3 = {"a":"alpha","b":"beta"}
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: Look at `Object.entries` (or `Object.keys` or `for-in`), perhaps also `Object.fromEntries`. All described fairly clearly on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/) For instance, you can get all of Object1's entries as an array of `[name, value]` arrays from `Object.entries`, use `map` to look up the value in `Object2` to get the new value, and return new `[name, value]` entries from `map`; use `fromEntries` to create the new object. Or just use a `for-in` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let obj3 = {};
Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([ key, val ]) => obj3[key] = obj2[val]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the `entries` (array of key-value pairs), and then reduce the resulting arrays to a new object:

```js
let Object1 = {"a":"1","b":"2"}
let Object2 = {"1":"alpha","2":"beta"}
let res = Object.entries(Object1).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>(acc[key] = Object2[value], acc), {})
console.log(res)
```